# Problems with percentage based max-width when floating

Tags: html, css

Inside a div, I'm floating a span. Within that span there is a child span that sets a max-width based on percentage (using percentage as I want it to be responsive).

**Problem**

The floated span has a sibling span that I want to sit right beside it. However, when I use percentage `max-width` for the child span, the container span remains at full width (containing mostly whitespace).

**Code**

CSS

```
.ellipsis-text {
    ...
    max-width: 40%;
    ...
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Floating span -->
<span class="pull-left">
    <!-- Child span with max-width -->
    <span class="ellipsis-text">
        ellipsis text that should cut off
    </span>
</span>
<span class="pull-left">
    second text
</span>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robcampo/LJqwW/6/

**Solution**

When I use pixels, it works, but as this should be responsive, percentages are better. Also, it works without the parent span floating, but I need this in my solution.

Is there a clean way to ensure that the parent span doesn't stretch 100%?

Comment: Your fiddle works fine on Chrome 34. What browser are you using?

Comment: I think the latest firefox (28.0) doesn't show the problem symptoms. 'second text' is placed on the left to 'ellipsis text'.

Comment: Could you otherwise post a render of the problem?

Comment: @David Chrome 34 also. Seems to be the same across the board. Are you definitely looking at the first line in the jsfiddle? Here's an updated version to avoid confusion: http://jsfiddle.net/robcampo/LJqwW/8/

Comment: @Exceptione FF 38 is broken for me. Can you confirm again with this jsfiddle which has been whittled down: http://jsfiddle.net/robcampo/LJqwW/8/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A floated element with unspecified width and height expands as much as its children. Percent width on children obviously will not work in this case. Here is an alternate solution which seems to work in responsive designs:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <span style="float: right;">second text</span>
    <span style="display: block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">ellipsis text that should cut off</span>
</div>
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/LJqwW/12/)

The drawback is that the order of spans has changed.

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution. This should work in most situations. 

I think the big problem with using percentages in my initial question is that it uses a percentage of its own span width, not that of its parent.

Comment: Yes, if the parent's dimensions are dependent on its contents (e.g. when it is floated or positioned) then the children cannot use percentage widths; or at least not the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Parent span should have display to block and float to left and it must have the width size manually to handle children width sizes.
child span should have display to block, float to left and the width size as percentage or px

Comment: thanks but I don't want to set a width on the parent span. I added display block to both spans and floated the child to left, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the rendering, you can clearly see that ellipsis text takes 40% from its parent.

I think you are using a broken browser at the moment.

[image: css result]
*rendering by Firefox 28 (Note FF 38 doesn't exist).*

```
<!-- Problem with this row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span class="pull-left">
            <span class="ellipsis-text">
                ellipsis text that should cut off
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="pull-left snd">
            second text
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 .ellipsis-text {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 40%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.ellipsis-text {
    background: rgba(0, 255, 255, .25);
}
.ellipsis-text-px {
    max-width: 40px;
}
.ellipsis-text-small {
    max-width: 5%;
}
.pull-left {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .25);
}
.pull-left.snd {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for diving deeper. This is the problem though ... I don't want the parent to expand to 100%. I want the parent span to just be as wide as its child span. Therefore, the yellow area in your pic is what I want removed. Should have been FF 28 btw.